# Inotify cannot detect valid path

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c, inotify

I m using inotify to get events of file changes in directory.

```
int fd = inotify_init();
for(const fs::path& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(filename)){
        if(fs::is_directory(p)) {
        // std::cout<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<p;
        int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd,ss.str().c_str(),IN_CLOSE_WRITE|IN_CREATE);
        if(wd<0)
            std::cout<<strerror(errno)<<std::endl;
        else
            store[wd] = ss.str();
        }
    }
```

`inotify_add_watch` is always throwing error `no such file or dir exists` even though the path is valid.
My os is `windows 10` and I m using WSL `ubuntu 20.04` on top of it and the paths which I m giving to inotify are like this `/mnt/c/Users/name/dir_name`

I have tested this program in another machine which has `20.04` as the OS, and it worked there. I think due to this `WSL` the issue is happening, not sure ( I m quite new to WSL).

Comment: It does look like a WSL problem with `inotify-tools` please see the linked post above.

Comment: @Raffa no its not working, I guess I will have to use windows system API instead linux for this